# What do you use for captcha?

Tags: recaptcha

Do you use captcha on your forms? If so, do you use Google Recaptcha or something else?

We don't want to get spam, but we also don't want to create a hurdle for people filling out the forms.

What's your recommendation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

I like [CiviHoneypot](https://github.com/elisseck/com.elisseck.civihoneypot).

I don't know why the author says to use ReCaptcha first.  I find ReCaptcha too invasive and I've successfully used CiviHoneypot to solve carder attacks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Thank you. What do you use in the field setting? Anything specific?

Comment: Pick something generic like name, url etc